# Can I use "rant" when also seeking a solution?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Some dictionaries say "rant" means to speak or shout in an aggressive, *unreasonable* way. Some even describe ranting as "nonsense"-talking.

Can "rant" be used in a situation where the speaker wants to talk about their serious problem to let the steam off but also seeks a solution?

For instance,

> Mark, I will call you later to rant about this [problem with an application] and maybe you will be able to solve it.

Comment: Mark doesn't want to be shouted at. When he sees it's you I doubt if he'll pick up the phone. The most successful rants arrive unannounced. You rant for a while, threaten never to use, say Virgin Media, ever again and let the person at the other end calm you down and offer you inducements. He/she may then solve the problem. Rants aren't directed at friends and colleagues, or at people who don't need your custom.

Comment: Btw, I've just realised 'custom' is used only in Britain to mean "Regular dealings with a shop or business by customers. Example: ‘if you keep me waiting, I will take my custom elsewhere.’" [https://www.lexico.com/definition/custom]

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I see, so if I share on social media a long comment on how I am missing a big feature in their app (in an aggressive manner, like: who the hell operates this, why there is no option for this?!), am I ranting about it?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - Americans do threaten to "take their custom elsewhere". Maybe not as much as we do, but still.

Comment: @towala3788: Exactly! Use plenty of exclamation marks!! (Good rant by the way.)

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Did you click that Lexico link? I must say I was a little surprised to see it, and "British" without a "chiefly". I didn't check any other dictionaries though.

Comment: I expect many Americans would understand that meaning of *custom* (unlike, say, the automotive meaning of *bonnet*). But I wouldn't disagree with a "chiefly British" indication.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, **vent**.

> Vent (v)—to express a negative emotion in a forceful and often unfair way
>
> *Example*
> I didn't mean to upset anyone; I just needed to vent.
> — [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vent)

Comment: The OP could use *rant* as originally proposed but *vent* is probably closer to the desired meaning.  Venting often includes ranting (and don't forget raving).